# Cross platform automatic node version setting

Tags: javascript, json, cross-platform, nvm

I work in an office where combination of Macs and Windows are used.
Every project has its node version and it can be tedious to switch to correct version even with nvm.
I would like to configure package json so that it automatically sets correct node version.
I have tried following:

`"prestart": "nvm use 0.12.1",`

and when zsh was warning me that `sh: nvm: command not found` I tried:

`sh ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.15.4`
with different variations but this just gets ignored.

Does anyone have a cross platform solution for this?